# Table of regression predictions for all pairings of two factors

Tags: r, linear-regression, tapply

For an assignment we are asked to provide predictions for all pairing of two factor variables in a table. I have two factors and a linear model. I would like to output a table such that rows are levels of one factor, columns are the levels of the other factor and the values in the table are the predicted values for those levels.

I have done the prediction easily enough but displaying it is causing the issues as no function seems to quite do the job. I had thought `tapply()` might do it but I can't seem to use my linear model as the function? Is there any way to output a two-way table of factors with the predictions from my linear model?

```
newdata = expand.grid(GenericFactor1 = c("1", "2", "3"), GenericFactor2 = c("10","20","30","40"))
pred = predict.lm(linear.model.lm, newdata)
newdata$pred = as.vector(pred)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an example, but note that we still cannot run this code because we don't have `linear.model.lm`. Could you please include the training of this model, perhaps with some synthetic data as input?

Comment: As it is a current assignment, I've altered the code to be generic but that is what I have so far. Where I have a table of the combinations of the two factors and then add the predictions as a 3rd column. I would then like to be able to display that but failing so far to figure it out.

Comment: Uh... why does there need to be synthetic data to test with? I thought the question was fairly simple. I have two factors and a linear model. That linear model predicts a vector of values. I would like to output a table such that rows are levels of one factor, columns are the levels of the other factor and the values in the table are the predicted values for those levels.

Comment: Well, for starters if we had a model on synthetic data as well as the expected output then it would be easy for those answering the question to demonstrate that their code outputs the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you have two factors and you want to create a table where the rows are associated with the values from the first factor, the columns are associated with the values from the second factor, and the data is the predictions of a model for the relevant pair of factor values. This sort of setup is well handled by the `outer` function:

```
outer(c(1, 2, 3), c(10, 20, 30, 40), function(x, y) {
  predict.lm(linear.model.lm, newdata=data.frame(GenericFactor1=x, GenericFactor2=y))
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was almost exactly what I wanted. The only problem is it's labeling the rows and columns with indexes rather than factor levels. I'm sure I'll figure that out though :)